# How to remove the version number entry from appstore connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app store account. I already have a version number `a.b.c` and its available in app-store and the status is *Ready for Sale*.

Accidentally I pressed add symbol and entered `a.b.d` and status is *Prepare for Submission*

But I want to delete the version number `a.b.d` from app store connect.

How can I do that?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't remove the new version placeholder, but you can edit the version number that the new version will have